# No partitioning defined in Many to Many conjugation table

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, many-to-many, relational-database, composite-primary-key

I have `Many to Many` relation between `jobs` and `eqtypes` so I have made a third table named `eqtype_jobs`. However, in this relation conjugation, normalization, table I did not make an independent primary key `id` for example, I just set both `job_id` and `eqtype_id` as a primary key. The following is the table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `eqtype_jobs` (
  `job_id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `eqtype_id` int(4) UNSIGNED NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

--
-- Indexes for dumped tables
--

--
-- Indexes for table `eqtype_jobs`
--
ALTER TABLE `eqtype_jobs`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`eqtype_id`,`job_id`),
  ADD KEY `job_id` (`job_id`);

--
-- Constraints for dumped tables
--

--
-- Constraints for table `eqtype_jobs`
--
ALTER TABLE `eqtype_jobs`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `eqtype_jobs_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`job_id`) REFERENCES `jobs` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `eqtype_jobs_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`eqtype_id`) REFERENCES `eqtypes` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

This is the first table that I omitted using independent primary key `id`. I have other Many to Many relations that I used and `id` in them before. However, phpMyAdmin shows the following notice when displaying `eqtype_jobs` table structure:

> **No partitioning defined!**

Do the cause of this message about partitioning due to the absence of an independent primary key, i,e `id`? or the composite primary key of the table is not defined well?! Does this notice about portions will negatively affects the performance in the future?!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, the message isn't saying anything bad about your table structure. From a grammar and UI aspect, it's a bit odd to have the exclamation point, but there's no problem here.

[Partitioning](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/partitioning.html) is a way of dividing up the way your data is stored on disk. The area of the Structure page that you see deals with partitioning (see photo), and when no partition is configured you see the notification that alarmed you.

[image: No partitions]

If a partition is configured, you'll see the parameters:

[image: Partition display]

So you can safely ignore the Partitioning portion of that page.

Comment: What if one wants to experiment with the suggested "partitioning". Could a performance boost be earned from partitioning? Could you maybe update your answer with a link to 'how to add partitioning', or further reading. Thanks

Comment: @MonkeyPuzzle I think that's really outside the scope of this question and falls more in to a general MySQL category so I think you should open your own question about partitioning (I'd be happy to take a look at it if you point me to it once you do so). In certain situations, a performance increase my be realized, but mostly if the partitions are spread across multiple storage devices.

Comment: Within phpMyAdmin, the "Partition table" button shown above gets you started with the interface (you must then select your partition criteria). The book "Mastering phpMyAdmin 3.3.x for Effective MySQL Management" has a chapter on creating partitions (https://www.packtpub.com/mapt/book/big_data_and_business_intelligence/9781849513548/17/ch17lvl1sec06/partitioning) , also the MySQL manual is pretty informative on the general principles.